# Find the "odd one out" and explain why

Tags: english

> i. I'm not used to the noise yet.
>
> ii. They used to work in a circus.
>
> iii. Didn't there use to be a shop there?
>
> iv. I never used to smoke.
>
> v. It didn't use to be so dirty.

Comment: I think it's a bit too broad. question_asker's answer could be valid but also a simple "iii, because that one is a question and the others not" could be valid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle.

Comment: I think it's more a linguistic question than a logical one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the intended answer, but:

> `ii. They used to work in a circus.` is the only one that does not use a negative.

Comment: saw the same, was unsure whether that could be it

Comment: Now that you pointed it out, it seems logical. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> 1. I'm not used to the noise yet.

because

> in this phrase, "use" does not refer to something in the past (used to be), but to adaption (be used to).

Comment: This is probably the intended answer